# how to do a check for a current url in php

Tags: php, url

I am wondering how to check for a current url with php. What I am trying to achieve is to load a .js file when a certain url is *active*. So lets say in the url is: **mydomain.nl**. In thast case there should a .js be loaded. But if the url is **mydomain.nl/pages** , the .js should not be loaded. How can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PHP_SELF` :-

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
?>
<script>
//Load JS file
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```